SHAP index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
I'm trying to do some DRL explainability stuff, but I'm having some problems with SHAP.
I have a shap_explanation object called shap_values, from which I should be able to select a column using shap_values[:, column_name], but I'm getting that error (index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0) instead.
I've also tried to select columns with shap_values[:, integer], which works fine with integer = 0 but doesn't with any other integers, since I get an error as if shap_values only had one column.
I'm 100% sure shap_values has multiple columns, as print(np.shape((shap_values)) gives me (501,11).
I'm also 100% sure shap_values has the right feature names, since print(shap_values.feature_names)) gives me what I expect.
shap_values is type <class 'shap._explanation.Explanation'>
Here's the part of the code where the error happens. Error happens at the last line shown.
    feature_names = ["T(t)", "C(t)", "W(t)", "T(t-3)", "F(t-3)", "T(t-2)", "F(t-2)", "T(t-1)", "F(t-1)", "T(t)", "F(t)"]
    obss = np.squeeze(obss)
    DF_obss = pd.DataFrame(data=obss, columns=feature_names)
    explainer = shap.Explainer(model=pred, masker=DF_obss)
    shap_values = explainer(DF_obss)

    print(DF_obss.head(10))
    print(type(shap_values))
    print(shap_values.feature_names)
    print(shap_values)
    print(np.shape(shap_values))

    for name in feature_names:
        shap.plots.scatter(shap_values[:,name], show=False)

obss is an array of size (501,11) with all the observations given to my agent during testing.
Here's the full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "(...)/explainer.py", line 107, in <module>
    explain(1, model, env)   File "(...)/explainer.py", line 102, in explain
    shap.plots.scatter(shap_values[:,name], show=False)
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/shap/_explanation.py", line 320, in __getitem__
    t = np.argwhere(np.array(self.output_names) == t)[0][0]

        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

I know that it should work because the code is copied from something else I did just a few days ago, and it worked just fine then. I genuinely have no idea what I did wrong.
Edit : Just realized I had two features with the same name, which is normal since two of the inputs of the model are the same (I know, it's weird), but changing that to have the two features have different name didn't fix it.
